# How can I get Ubuntu 14.04 to recognize my second monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics, intel

I know 14.04 is extremely out of date... but I use it for work. 2 monitors on 14.04 would be heavenly.

My workstation has dual DisplayPort. Dual monitors work as expected on Windows 10. Switching to Ubuntu 14.04, only the primary DisplayPort (always the "top" one on the IO shield, never the bottom) is initialized. I can tell because the bad port causes a "No signal" message to whichever monitor is plugged into it, regardless of the monitor or cable. So the "detect" option in Ubuntu's Display settings is useless. This seems like a blatant driver issue, but I'd like input on the best course of action for getting dual monitors to work on 14.04. Here's `lspci`:

```
$ sudo lspci -v
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e98 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0942
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] #1b
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] #13
```

[Here's the value for Graphics in "Details"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qZHN.png) (Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits))

On Windows, the Intel HD 630 Graphics driver for my Coffee Lake Intel CPU works like a charm. BIOS Video option is set on "Auto" (as opposed to Intel), which makes no difference.

Do I *really* have to [install Intel Graphics Stack Recipe from scratch](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2018q1-intel-graphics-stack-recipe)? This seems like the least user-friendly option, and I'm not even sure that it would resolve my problem.

I've tried the Intel Linux Graphics Installer, but this has been discontinued as it is no longer on the https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads page.

I have yet to try GRUB options. Willing to attempt anything that might work... except downgrading display manager to `gdm` from `lightdm`, as I've tried this and it sort of ruined my OS.